# Vector Spaces are Free Objects

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, soft-question, category-theory, coordinate-systems

Warning: I know little linear algebra and my assertions below may all be incorrect.
         I am interested in lists --i.e., free monoids-- and my interest has led me to
         [finite-dimensional] vector spaces.

---

Let  be any field, then we can freely equip any [finite] set S with a -vector space
$F(S) = (S → )$, a set of functions where vector addition is performed pointwise,
and likewise for the other vector operations. Moreover any function
$S → ||$ from $S$ to the underlying set of a vector space  can be extended to
a linear operator $F(S) → $ that behaves the same on elements of $S$ construed as vectors of $F(S)$.

That is, $F$ is a “free functor”: It constructs the least vector space that contains a (copy of a) given set.

It is known that every vector space  admits a basis β and so is isomorphic to $F(β)$
--which is essentially the dual space of .
That is, every vector space is free; i.e., is in the image of functor $F$.

Of-course we have to *choose* a basis to realise a vector space as a free object; there is
no canonical basis.

( Aside: With this in-hand, we can easily prove equi-dimensional spaces are necessarily
  isomorphic: That they're equi-dimensional means their basis are in bijection, but free
  objects are unique up to unique isomorphism and so their F-images must be unique
  up to unique isomorphism as well. That is, $ ≅ ^{dim } = ^{dim } ≅ $. Neat stuff! )

---

Questions:

1. *Intuitively* why is it that vector spaces admit basis.

   - I'm not interested in a proof.
   - For example, why is it that monoids or rings are not always generated by some set,
     but vector spaces are. The definition of a vector space does not immediately give rise to a basis.
2. All [finite dimensional] vector spaces admit basis and so the objects of , the category
   of finite dimensional vector spaces and linear operators, are all images of a free functor.
   (Assuming we have a way to *choose* basis.)

   - Is there a name for categories whose objects are all isomorphic to an image of a free functor?
   - What other examples of such categories are there?
   - Are there any constructions that produce such categories.
3. Lists over a set $S$ are isomorphic to $⋃_{n ∈ ℕ} Sⁿ$ and provide the *free monoid* over
   a given set $S$. Why is it that lists, whence monoids, are far more prevalent than their
   vector space counterparts within computing science.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that the claim that *every* vector space can be given a basis requires the Axiom of Choice (or at least goes beyond ZF). In a similar vein, the claim fails in constructive foundations and I believe it fails much more severely.

Comment: It's at best difficult to explain something "intuitively" because any intuitive explanation will only work if you have the necessary intuitions. Different people have different intuitions. In a sense, you're asking for someone else to do the work of understanding for you. For finite-dimensional vector spaces, the process is fairly easy... pick any nonzero vector, then keep picking a vector not in the span of previously picked vectors. After a finite number of steps you will stop and at that point you have a basis.

Comment: Intuitively, you can say that this process works for infinite vector spaces, you just need an infinite or even uncountable number of steps. But that's just a fuzzy way of describing Zorn's lemma.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Why must that process necessarily terminate? --in the finite dimensional setting.

Comment: By definition, a finite-dimensional vector space is one with a finite basis. If it didn’t terminate it would be an infinite dimensional vector space.