# Terminology for a category whose objects are all free

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

The question is straight forward:

Is there a standard terminology for a category whose objects are all free? (defined by the universal property)

The prime example I had in mind was the category of $\Bbbk$-vector spaces, but I think for any algebraic structure, the subcategory consisting of the free objects would be interesting to consider.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925813/vector-spaces-are-free-objects

Comment: I asked this as a side question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157974/varieties-where-every-algebra-is-free) once, and got some suggestions (my favorite was "panteleutheric"), but nothing standard. It's a very special property, as I learned in the answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion of a "free object" doesn't make sense in an arbitrary category. Note that the universal property of e.g. free groups refers to maps from a set to the underlying set of a group. So you should have something like a forgetful functor to the category of sets in order to talk about "free objects".

If you're looking at a category of algebraic structures, in the sense of the category of [algebras for a monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Algebras_for_a_monad) $T$, then the subcategory of free algebras is (equivalent to) the [Kleisli category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category) of $T$.

Comment: True, I wanted to specify  to talk about concrete category. Yes, I think this is what I'm looking for. Thank you!